# Can macro-dependant access specifiers in a class definition result in undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, undefined-behavior

Let's say I have the following two class definitions (only the access specifier for `bar()` is different, everything else is the same):

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void foo();
    void bar();   // bar() is public

private:
    int member;
};
```

and

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void foo();

private:
    void bar();   // bar() is private
    int member;
};
```

Does a compiler consider the classes to be "different" in terms of what code the compiler produces? (Or in other words: Does the compiler treat it differently apart from access permission checking?)

This is the same question as: Can the following code cause any trouble like *undefined behavior*? (Provided that it is compiled in different units, with or without X being defined, and linked together afterwards.)

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void foo();

#ifdef X
private:
#endif
    void bar();

private:
    int member;
};
```

I'm interested in a compiler-independent answer as well as in a GCC-specific one (as this is my primary target compiler).

This becomes interesting if we want to "simulate" things like `package private` from the Java world in C++ by defining a specific macro within the "package".

Comment: Since `#define private public` is common "hack" to make Unit testing - then it works at least for `gcc`. But I guess this is UB per std C++ (however not sure - so comment - not answer ;)

Comment: Thanks @PiotrNycz, I want to do a `#define libprivate private` / `public` depending whether or not the header is compiled from within the library. So this is the same "hack" than `#define private public` (but it causes much less pain :D)

Comment: What about `friend`? It is not uncommon for classes within one library to be friends ;)

Comment: @PiotrNycz This will grant FULL access to the target class, but I don't want to loose the "real" private access specifier. Just add another "library private" one like Javas "package private". However, I can imagine defining libprivate to be still private within the library when compiled in release mode while adding all library classes as friends. But when developing the library changing the friends every now and then will be a pain, also the missing "real" private.

Comment: btw, as an aside, [Access to private members. That's easy!](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely undefined behaviour to violate the one-definition rule, which requires that all definitions of the same class type be identical.

Note that the memory layout of a class is only specified *within each access level*, so changing access levels can very realistically lead to a different memory layout of the class.

Comment: Good point. Can you cite a reference for the 2nd point that the "memory layout of a class is only specified within each access level"?

Comment: @RealzSlaw: In C++11, it's 9.2/13.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that this would not be a good idea:

> changing the access rights to some functions or data members, for
>   example from private to public. With some compilers, this information
>   may be part of the signature. If you need to make a private function
>   protected or even public, you have to add a new function that calls
>   the private one.
>
> ― [Policies/Binary Compatibility Issues With C++](http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++)

However, I don't think this should result in undefined behavior, but rather should result in a link error or symbol loading error.

**UPDATE:**

Testing on GCC (4.6.1), changing access rights worked without a problem.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful link and quote. I wonder which compilers those are... For GCC I successfully tested the linkage of objects with classes having different access specifiers. Now I'm just wondering which compilers I "kick out" of my compatibility list when doing things like this. Do you know more about that?

Comment: I tested gcc myself, and it works without a problem (gcc (GCC) 4.6.1). No, I don't know which compilers fail, but if I find anything, I'll add it.

Comment: @leemes http://mearie.org/documents/mscmangle/index.en#function would seem to rule MSVC out. However, it would be best to test it and I cannot.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Thought about throwing away MSVC support for my library though... But I see a possible solution: See the 4th comment on the question.